# add custom imageview on particular x position in linearlayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

i am adding imageview on selection of item from suggestion list of edittext. below is my code:

```
edt1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String path = adapter1.getSelectedItem(position).getPath();

                Bitmap btmp = getBitmapFromAsset("imgs", path);

                int pos = edt1.getSelectionStart();

                String myText = edt1.getText().toString();

                String subStringed = myText.substring(0, pos);
                String[] parts = subStringed.split(" ");
                String lastWord = parts[parts.length - 1];

                Log.e("WORD--->", "LAST---> "+lastWord);

                Log.e("WORD--->", "POS---> "+pos);

                int newpos = pos - lastWord.length()-1;

                Log.e("WORD--->", "NEW POS---> "+newpos);


                Layout layout = edt1.getLayout();
                int line = layout.getLineForOffset(newpos);
                int baseline = layout.getLineBaseline(line);
                int ascent = layout.getLineAscent(line);
                float x = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(newpos);
                float y = baseline + ascent;


                if(parts.length>imgList.size()){
                    ImageView iv = new ImageView(getActivity());
                    iv.setImageBitmap(btmp);
                    iv.setX(x);
                    llImgContainer.addView(iv);
                    imgList.add(iv);
                }else{
                    imgList.get(parts.length-1).setImageBitmap(btmp);
                    imgList.get(parts.length-1).setX(x);
                }

            }
        });
```

i am adding image into linearlayout which is upon edittext at last word's starting position. but its not set perfectly on x position. you can see that in below image:

[image]

Red line is starting position of word and set image on that position. but you can see above edittext, images are not set perfectly..Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Share your desired output image

Comment: i already shared with question.

Comment: You want circled images on red lines?

Comment: yes, at that x position.

Comment: i am not sure if this helps or even is what you need, but did you try to use `AutocompleteTextview`, you can use a custom adapter with custom layout for each item, just like listView

Comment: hehehe.. @Yazan out of question suggestion..

Comment: @MunimJi :( sorry, i just felt like you are re-implementing something already exists, could not understand what u need :) sorry again